# Bluetooth keyboard, Volume keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth, fluxbox

I have a lenovo kt-155 bluetooth keyboard. The volume keys work occasionally. Has anyone managed to make this device do the right thing consistently?

When it works `xev` reports the key-presses as:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 2072557749, (111,-13), root:(112,821),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 2072557852, (111,-13), root:(112,821),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 2072558407, (110,-13), root:(111,821),
    state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 2072558572, (110,-13), root:(111,821),
    state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When it doesn't they look like:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Did you also try to go the "easier" way? Is there a consistency (of keys working) short after booting? Did you check if some process started later can't be interfering with key event handling?

Comment: @miroxlav - no, I haven't. And I'm not sure how I'd check what kind of process I need to be looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The media keys on my keyboard don't work. I install alsamixergui, map a keyboard shortcut to it (pause/break key or modifier-A for alsa). Pop it open with the shortcut, press up/down to adjust volume, then alt-F4 to close it.